# Need help dumping private APIs

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, iphone-privateapi

I want to experiment with private APIs, more precisely, CoreTelephony private API,
And I understood that I need to use class-dump or class-dump-z to dump the private header files.
The thing is, that both class-dump and class-dump-z gives me an empty output with just the app's credits (actually class-dump-z dumped 2 header files, one is empty, the other just "include" the empty one).
I've been using the following flags on both of the above apps

```
-o ~/Desktop -H /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
```

As you see from the above location, I'm using iOS 8.0 (Don't know if it matters)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that path is right?  On my machine, it's `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony`.

Comment: Hi Nate, appreciate your reply. I've just made a mistake when posting this question, I'll edit it. Anyways, I'm using the same path as you've posted. are you able to dump the header files yourself?

Comment: Hmmm.  No, I'm not able to.  Maybe Apple did something to inhibit reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Guess it is some sort of iOS8 SDK protection.
I've downloaded Xcode 5.1, extracted iOS7 SDK from there, and dumped the header files the same way, without any problems.